# How to get excel UDF to return an actual datetime instead of general or double?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

Hi I have created a an Excel UDF that returns an array of string, dates and integers. Excel however converts my datetime values into double and I therefore have to manually select the values and convert to short date within excel. If i convert date to string within my c# code, excel recognizes it as general so i cannot grab the value for that cell. Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show some code so there isn't guess work on everyone's behalf.

Comment: It's just a general question that I have. I can create a simple excel UDF that returns an object. If I return a datetime then excel automatically converts it to a double since that's how excel portrays dates. I can select the cell with that double number and then format the cell to short date to actually see the correct format. However I was wondering if there was a workaround to this so I don't need to go through the process of clicking the cell and converting it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, Excel does not have an internal representation for values as a date/time - dates are just doubles with different formatting applied. Some built-in functions, like `=TODAY()`, are special-cased by Excel internally and automatically apply date formatting. Excel has no mechanism for user-defined functions to opt in to this special behaviour.

One workaround, though not one I would suggest, is to run a macro that changes the formatting of the calling cells after the calculation has completed. You store which cells need to be reformatted (based on Application.Caller / xlfCaller), and run a macro that changes the cell formats - either from a calculation event handler or scheduled with Application.OnTime.

It's rather ugly.

Comment: Ah thank you for clearing this up for me! Also going a bit off topic but great work on the excel DNA.